# Not able run the script based on the results of java program

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I have a Java program that is populating data into xyz table and there is dataimporter script that is populating data from that xyz table to other tables.

I am trying to run the dataimporter only on the successful completion of Java Program.

Following is my script. The same kind of logic I am using at diff places and it's working fine.
I tried echoing both $? and $retVal but don't see any echo statement result.

```
#!/bin/bash

//// ---code----

echo ".jar execution startd...currentMilliseconds"_$(date +%s%3N) >> ${LOGFILE} 2>&1
java -jar ./testservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ${ENV}  >> ${LOGFILE} 2>&1
retVal=$?
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error" >> ${LOGFILE} 2>&1
else
        echo "processing startd...currentMilliseconds"_$(date +%s%3N) >> ${LOGFILE} 2>&1
                bash -x ~/bin/DataImporter
        echo "processing completed...currentMilliseconds"_$(date +%s%3N) >> ${LOGFILE} 2>&1
fi
```

Could you please help to execute the DataImporter script on the successful completion of Java program completion? I am not able to see any if/else part output. Script is not logging any after java -jar command to investigate the issue. Java code is just stand-alone service processing via main function.

Comment: Are you shure that the java program exits?

Comment: Yes, I see that in the log file.

Comment: Are you saying you see neither the "Error" nor the "processing start" output?

Comment: @glenn jackman Correct. I even tried executing java command and then dataimporter after that directly without checking any condition but still it is not executing dataimporter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using the shell's `-e` "errexit" option. Change your script to

```sh
# log everything
exec >> "$LOGFILE" 2>&1

echo ".jar execution startd...currentMilliseconds_$(date +%s%3N)"
if java -jar ./testservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "$ENV"; then
    echo "processing startd...currentMilliseconds_$(date +%s%3N)"
    bash -x ~/bin/DataImporter
    echo "processing completed...currentMilliseconds_$(date +%s%3N)"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
```

Comment: its printing the "Error"

Comment: Run the java program manually and check the exit status. It must be non-zero. What is in the logfile? Actual errors? It is really a problem if the java program exits non-zero?

Comment: irrespective of status it should execute if or else block right? I don't see any echo executed....

Comment: "don't see any echo" -- with your code or with mine? Do you have `set -e` in your script? If you do, then you'll never get to your `retVal=$?` line because the script will abort with the non-zero exit of the java command.

Comment: yes...I had set -e in the script....I removed it and it is working now.... thanks.

Comment: With my code, you can keep `set -e` because a non-zero result is handled by `if`

Comment: I tried your solution as well but it was not working....maybe because of set -e